# Whitelabel Error Error Page with SpringBoot

Tags: javascript, java, reactjs, spring-boot, port

I developed an application with SpringBoot that has webservices and includes the front-office generated and coded with ReactJs.
By default, this starts on port 8080. In order to make it easier to enter the URL, I wanted to switch the application to port 80.
To do this, I added the code below in the configuration class:

```
@Bean
public EmbeddedServletContainerCustomizer containerCustomizer() {
    return (container -> {
        container.setPort(80);
    });
}
```

When I launch the application from STS (OS: windows 10), I have no issues. On the other hand, when I launch it with `java -jar` on the final environment (Ubuntu 18.04), the application starts well, but displays the following error:

[image: error]

I tested, the call of webservices from postman and they work well. The webservices address has been updated in the front-office code.

Do you have any idea how to solve the problem?

Comment: 'server.error.whitelabel.enabled=false' ----add this line in you application.properties file .... it will show full error message , error message will be help you to understand the problem

Comment: I did it and restarted the application. Here is the new error displayed: "org.springframework.web.util.NestedServletException: Request processing failed; nested exception is org.thymeleaf.exceptions.TemplateInputException: Error resolving template "error", template might not exist or might not be accessible by any of the configured Template Resolvers"

Comment: I solved the problem, I had put the "containerCustomizer" method in an undeclared class in "@Configuration". In addition to that, in the annotated class"@Configuration", this method already existed. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

just put the following line in application.properties :-
server.port = 80

if you don't have application.properties file create it in src/main/resources